# STM32, mass storage device. Windows просит отформатировать диск после записи большого файла

Tags: c, usb, stm32

Всем привет!
Хочу организовать флешку на основе STM32F105RBT + AT45DB041.
Суть проблемы: после записи файла (или группы файлов с совокупным...) размером более 12 KB, после переподключения устройства к ПК, windows7 просит отформатировать диск.
Все работает нормально, если:

1. Размер файла (-файлов) <= 12KB
2. Не переподключать устройство к ПК

Память работает в режиме 264 байта/страницу. Всего, 2048 страниц.
Так как передача данных устройству идет блоками по 512 байт, я модифицировал код вычисления объема

```
int8_t STORAGE_GetCapacity_FS(uint8_t lun, uint32_t *block_num, uint16_t *block_size)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 3 */
  *block_num  = 1024; 
  *block_size = 512; 
  return (USBD_OK);
  /* USER CODE END 3 */
}
```

Модифицировал функции чтения/записи USB таким образом, что пишу один блок данных в две страницы памяти по 256 байт.

```
int8_t STORAGE_Write_FS(uint8_t lun, uint8_t *buf, uint32_t blk_addr, uint16_t blk_len)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 7 */

  AT45dbxx_WritePage(buf, 256, (uint16_t)blk_addr*2);
  AT45dbxx_WritePage(buf+256, 256, (uint16_t)blk_addr*2+1);
  return (USBD_OK);

  /* USER CODE END 7 */
}

int8_t STORAGE_Read_FS(uint8_t lun, uint8_t *buf, uint32_t blk_addr, uint16_t blk_len)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 6 */
                   
    AT45dbxx_ReadPage(buf, 256, (uint16_t)blk_addr*2);
    AT45dbxx_ReadPage(buf+256, 256, (uint16_t)blk_addr*2+1);

    return (USBD_OK);
  /* USER CODE END 6 */
}
```

Функции для работы с памятью работают корректно во всем диапазоне страниц.

UPD.
Флешка перед записью форматируется средствами windows.
В процессе записи и короткого файла, и "длинного" запись идет и в начальные сектора: 0, 1, 2...

Comment: Отформатируйте виндой флешку. И не трогайте первые сектора. Там служебная информация от типе и количестве разделов. И непонятно как вы пишете без таблицы секторов. Каким форматом FAT , FAT32 ?

Comment: Да, я форматирую из под винды. Выше описанное поведение проявляется на отформатированной виндой устройстве.  Я отслеживал сектора, в которые идет запись. Почему-то действительно, в сектора 0, 1, 2.. винда писала что-то в процесе записи памяти.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Решил проблему, исправлением uint16_t page на uint32_t page и все работает. Всем спасибо!

```
void AT45dbxx_ErasePage(uint32_t page)
{
    page = page << AT45dbxx.Shift; // AT45dbxx.Shift = 9 For 264 byte per page 
    AT45dbxx_Resume();
    AT45dbxx_WaitBusy();
    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(_45DBXX_CS_GPIO,_45DBXX_CS_PIN,GPIO_PIN_RESET);
    AT45dbxx_Spi(AT45DB_PGERASE); // CMD 0x81
    AT45dbxx_Spi((page >> 16) & 0xff);
    AT45dbxx_Spi((page >> 8) & 0xff);
    AT45dbxx_Spi(page & 0xff);
    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(_45DBXX_CS_GPIO,_45DBXX_CS_PIN,GPIO_PIN_SET);
    AT45dbxx_WaitBusy();
}
void AT45dbxx_WritePage(uint8_t *Data,uint16_t len,uint32_t page)
{
    page = page << AT45dbxx.Shift;  // AT45dbxx.Shift = 9 For 264 byte per page 
    AT45dbxx_Resume();
    AT45dbxx_WaitBusy();
    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(_45DBXX_CS_GPIO,_45DBXX_CS_PIN,GPIO_PIN_RESET);
    AT45dbxx_Spi(AT45DB_MNTHRUBF1);  // CMD 0x82
    AT45dbxx_Spi((page >> 16) & 0xff);
    AT45dbxx_Spi((page >> 8) & 0xff);
    AT45dbxx_Spi(page & 0xff);
    HAL_SPI_Transmit(&_45DBXX_SPI,Data,len,100);
    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(_45DBXX_CS_GPIO,_45DBXX_CS_PIN,GPIO_PIN_SET);
    AT45dbxx_WaitBusy();    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Еще была подобная проблемв с маленьким медленным диском на 32 Кб. Требовалось обязательное "Безопасное извлечение" после любой процедуры записи (зписсь, форматирование, переименование, перемещение). Интересно что Windows смог его отформатировать, а для форматирования с помощью FatFS было недостаточно секторов